# Hyper-V fail-over network replication ports (do i need HTTPS inbound to source server?)

Tags: hyper-v, replication, hyper-v-server-2012

I have replicaton of a local server to a remote server and all is fine (the remote server is enabled as a replica server, with HTTPS inbound).

In the event i perform a planned failover to the remote server, how do changes get replicated back, are they over the outbound local-to-remote HTTPS connection or by some other means?

My local server is not enabled as a replica server and as such says nothing about enabling inbound HTTPs.

Appreciate pointers as not been able to find any docs on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable reverse replication you have to enable your primary host to receive replication as well.

When you reverse replication it matches the GUID and replicates to the original VM so don't worry about the replica storage location setting on the primary host, that is for replicas not already on the host.

[Replication Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj134207(v=ws.11)#set-up-the-primary-server-to-receive-replication)